# Using netctl, how can i force the use of only the configured DNS and ignore those provided by the DHCP?

Tags: dns, dhcp

In the according **netctl profile** i use `IP=dhcp` and `DNS=('some_host')`.

In addition, the **DHCP server** offers a DNS at 192.168.1.1.

I end up with this content in **/etc/resolv.conf**:

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver some_host
```

Actually I want **/etc/resolv.conf** to look like this:

```
nameserver some_host
```

Comment: Which distro are you using?

Comment: Arch - though the distro used may only have minor implications on the topic, no? :)

Comment: Apparently the most feasible way to go about this is to deny dhcp to write to /etc/resolv.conf: `echo 'nohook resolv.conf' >> /etc/dhcpcd.conf`

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to `/etc/resolvconf.conf`

```
name_servers=some_host
```